# Handle firebase tracking in clean architecture

Tags: android, ios, firebase, clean-architecture

I am confused for arranging firebase event source code in clean architecture. Should I move them to use case (domain layer) before accessing data from presenter layer. Thanks for your support!!!

Comment: Dear @LamLe - Hope this article will help you: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8